# Installing Ruby - Digital Ocean - RVM - Unstable ruby version - Can't install Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, configuration, rubygems

I am trying to install Ruby & Rails on DigitalOcean droplet, I have downloaded ruby 2.5.1 with RVM but when I check version it says 2.31 and when I list available versions I get only 2.5.1.

I have tried rvm use 2.5.1 I got below problem

[image]

I fix it by running `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` , then `rvm use 2.5.1` and run `bundle install`, I get the following error,

> can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

[image]

Below show the unstable issues faced from RVM and ruby versions

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I ssh into the server and run ruby -v, I get 2.5.1, then if I run

> /bin/bash --login

I check ruby -v, its 2.5.1

Comment: Did you install `rvm` with `sudo`? If so, then you may need to uninstall and try again. Under normal circumstances, `rvm` does not require `sudo`, and will not work properly if you installed it with `sudo`.

Comment: In other words, your issue is that (1) `bunder` is not installed, and (2) `gem install bundler` does not work (because you installed RVM with `sudo`?), and (3) running `sudo gem install bundler` is installing the gem in a different environment, which won't help.

Comment: I have uninstalled it and reinstalled without sudo, get this error from bundler  1Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile'

Comment: What is the output of `bundle -v` and `which bundle`? `git_source` was added in bundler version `1.16.0` -- So again, I'm guessing your environment might be messed up due to the way things had been installed.

Comment: @selim dont install with rvm, Install Ruby on Rails with rbenv (RVM is more resourceful but rbenv is lightweight which makes it a strong contender for RVM)

Answer (score 1):

install ruby 2.5.1 first, from your image it seems rvm already installed correctly
you just need to install it (it shows from your list command)

```
rvm install 2.5.1
# this to install version 2.5.1
rvm use 2.5.1
# active ruby 2.5.1
ruby -v
# check your version and make sure it said 2.5.1
```

to install bundler to your home directory use

```
# after you active ruby 2.5.1 then install bundler
gem install bundler 
# my suggestion do not install with sudo
# in case you still has write problem below is other solution suggested [from here][1]
gem install bundler --user-install
```

This will install Bundler **into your home directory**. Note that you will need to append ~/.gem/ruby//bin to your $PATH variable to use bundle.

Comment: now I get the following error:   ' Undefined local variable or method `git_source' for Gemfile`, also how to add to $PATH variable

Comment: ruby -v is 2.5.1, the i run gem instal bundler, it download bundler 2.01, but when i run bundle install, I get this error, can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException

Comment: how about update bundler first with this command gem update bundler

Comment: Tried it several times but still failing